# How can I disable Airplane Mode?

Tags: release-loki, networking

I have a problem with *Airplane Mode* (AM) in elementary OS Loki (latest release, updated as of today). I am not sure whether this is a Gnome issue (see for instance this [thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=211250)), a Pantheon issue or something completely different.

**Here is my problem**: I cannot disable AM; if the radiobutton is flipped, AM remains in the same state. I can only choose from VPN and Proxy, but no network interfaces are present.

Invoking the following command

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

returns that no devices (`hci0: bluetooth` and `phy0: Wireless LAN`) are soft or hard blocked. I tried

```
sudo rfkill unblock 1
```

which correspondes to `phy0`. Also tried blocking and unblocking it. There is a hardware switch on the laptop. I have tried to switch this back and forth, and it does indeed make `hci0` and `phy0` to appear as soft blocked. This does not yield a solution, though.

Let us look in the Network manager's internal state:

```
cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

gives

```
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
```

OK, so that is not it... Moreover, `ifconfig` states that only the loopback interface is enabled. Running

```
ifconfig [dev] up
```

makes the device show up when running `ifconfig`, but it still does not give me a network connection. Subsequently running `down` and `up` does not remedy either.

I tried starting elementary OS in recovery mode. First, I enable network and then, resume the process arriving at the desktop. Now, the network works perfectly (however, the network settings still reports that Airplane Mode is ON), so it is clearly not a hardware issue.

Finally, I have also tried resetting to defaults (button in the About window). This had virtually no effect at all on the network manager. I *really* want to avoid reinstalling elementary OS for this reason.

Any hints?

Comment: If it has any relevance, the laptop is a HP Elitebook 840 G3.

Comment: @Daniel The intention was not for this to be a bug report, rather a question on how to resolve the current state.

Comment: I've reopened the question. In the future, please phrase titles as a question and make sure that your question is clear. This post reads as a bug report and it's not very clear that you're intending to ask a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving this problem is to do

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-desktop
```

It might seem a bit drastic but it works.